# How to use Delimited data in WHERE condition during Join Query?

Tags: sql, oracle

Lets say i have two tables EMPLOYEE and INCHARGE_ROOM , EMPLOYEE.INCHARGE_ROOMS has | delimted data of INCHARGE_ROOM.ID

#### EMPLOYEE

> ID      NAME               INCHARGE_ROOMS 
>   1        K           1|2|3|4
>   2        S           2|4|5

### INCHARGE_ROOM

> INCHARGE_ROOM_ID      INCHARGE_ROOM_NAME
>   1                                        RED
>   2                                       BLUE
>   3                                      YELLOW
>   4                                       ORANGE
>   5                                       BLACK

If i want to

> SELECT ALL THE ROOMS FOR WHICH K IS INCHARGE.

The Expected result is

> NAME                               INCHARGE_ROOM
>   K                                                RED
>   K                                                BLUE
>   K                                                YELLOW
>   K                                                ORANGE

Comment: yes,i know. But this is the situation i have. It is for ORACLE.THX.

Comment: I STRONGLY suggest you start here. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried to do this once; it didn't work well.

SQL is designed to have tables linking together, so instead of the incharge_rooms column, it should have another table `incharge_rooms(employee_id,room_id)`. (primary key is on both columns)

Then you just join them together to get whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
select e.NAME, ir.INCHARGE_ROOM_NAME as INCHARGE_ROOM
from INCHARGE_ROOM ir
inner join EMPLOYEE e on ir.INCHARGE_ROOM_ID  like INCHARGE_ROOMS + '|%'
    or ir.INCHARGE_ROOM_ID  like '%|' + INCHARGE_ROOMS + '|%'
    or ir.INCHARGE_ROOM_ID  like '%|' + INCHARGE_ROOMS
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic example of how not to structure the data.  Bill Karwin's book '[SQL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356557) [AntiPatterns](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2670985/SQL-Antipatterns)' calls it *JayWalking*.

Your table design should be fixed.  If you can't fix it, then you have to use DBMS-specific techniques to undo the damage done by the broken schema design.

You need 3 tables, not 2:

```
Employee (EmployeeID, Name)
InChargeRoom (InChargeRoomID, InChargeRoomName)
EmpInCharge (EmployeeID, InChargeRoomID)
```

Then you can do a simple 3-way join to get the required result trivially.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't change the structure (which many people can't because of legacy code or third-party code):

```
select 
  emp.name as NAME
  , room.incharge_room_name as INCHARGE_ROOM
from employee emp
inner join incharge_room room 
  on ('%|' || room.incharge_room_id || '|%' like '|' || emp.incharge_rooms || '|');
```